# How to access a css style property inside a html element for use in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a appearing and disappearing object that falls down a column in my html and css using the Y axis. the position constantly updates every 1 second. this is the line of code that appears since my JS will create and move the falling object at 1 second intervals, kinda like tetris.

Now in the translateY(360px) section, the (..px) portion will constantly increment by 30 px at a time. I am creating a function that will console.log a hit if a key is pressed only when the translateY(600px) reaches 600px as stated. But my conditionals in the function so far are not working.

It might be the way I am accessing the property value but I am not sure. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

here is my function:

```
<div class="falling-object" style="transform: translateY(360px);"><img src="./assets/note.jpg"></div>

function hitJudge(keyPressed) {
  // Check if a note element is present
  let note = document.querySelector('.falling-object');

  // Get the computed style of the falling object
  let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(note);
  let translateY = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('transform').split(',')[5].trim();

  // Check if the falling object's position is at the desired translateY value, note is true, and keyPressed is true
  if (translateY === '600px' && keyPressed === true) {
    console.log('hit');
  } else {
    console.log('miss');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the fact that the transform property is a matrix, and the translateY value is the sixth value in the matrix. It's a bit error-prone to extract it using string manipulation. Instead, I recommend using transform property methods.

Here's how you can modify your function:

```
function hitJudge(keyPressed) {
  // Check if a note element is present
  let note = document.querySelector('.falling-object');

  // Get the computed style of the falling object
  let transform = window.getComputedStyle(note).transform;
  
  // Parse the transform matrix to get the translateY value
  let translateY = parseInt(transform.split(',')[5]);

  // Check if the falling object's position is at the desired translateY value, note is true, and keyPressed is true
  if (translateY === 600 && keyPressed === true) {
    console.log('hit');
  } else {
    console.log('miss');
  }
}
```

This code uses parseInt() to convert the extracted value to an integer, making the comparison more straightforward. Additionally, it compares against 600 instead of '600px' since the value is retrieved as an integer. Adjusting your condition in this way should help resolve the issue.